# Search function to include space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a search function that would allow me to search Word 1  Word 2  ...  Word 'n'.

The code below allows me to search through table rows. Results are presented when there is a 1:1 match (Ignoring case). I would like to search using combinations separated by spaces.

Table data sample as below.
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD.pdf
EEE_FFF_GGG_HHH.pdf

HTML

```
                    <script>
                    $(function(){
                        $(function(){
                            var requestUri = "<<URL>>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<<Folder>>')/Files?$filter=(substringof(%27.pdf%27,Name)%20or%20substringof(%27.PDF%27,Name))&$top=1000";
                               $.ajax({
                                  url: requestUri,
                                  type: "GET",
                                  headers: {
                                      "accept":"application/json; odata=verbose"
                                  },
                                  success: onSuccess,
                    });

                      function onSuccess(data) {
                         var objItems = data.d.results;
                         var tableContent = '<table id="Table" style="width:100%"><tbody>';

                         for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
                             tableContent += '<tr>';
                             tableContent += '<td>' + [i+1] + '</td>';
                             tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Name  + '</td>';
                             tableContent += '<td>' + "<a target='iframe_j' href='<<URL>>" + objItems[i].ServerRelativeUrl + "'>" + "View" + "</a>" + '</td>';
                             tableContent += '</tr>';
                     }
                       $('#TDGrid').append(tableContent);
                       }
                      });
                    });

                    </script>

                    <div id="div">
                    <input class="form-control mb-2" id="TDSearch" type="text" placeholder=" Search">
                       <table id='Table' class="table table-striped table-sm small">
                         <tr>
                          <td>
                              <div id="TDGrid" style="width: 100%"></div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                     </table>
                    </div>
```

Current search function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#TDSearch").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#TDGrid tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Put more code and use snippets, it's hard to understand what you're looking for.

Comment: the filter callback function isn't returning anything.  what is the filter supposed to do?

Comment: Hi the filter callback is supposed to return rows of the rest api output that matches search query

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string to array and then make a function, which will check match for strings of that array.

Something like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#TDSearch").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var valueArr = value.split(' ');
    $("#TDGrid tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle(checkIfValuePresent($(this).text().toLowerCase(), valueArr));
    });
  });
});

function checkIfValuePresent(currRowText, valuesarr) {
  let isfound = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < valuesarr.length; i++) {
    if (currRowText.indexOf(valuesArr[i] > -1)) {
      isfound = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return isfound;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='TDSearch'>
```

Answer (score 0):

split on space, join all strings with `|` between them for a combined regex string search, case insensitive.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#TDSearch").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#TDGrid tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle(new RegExp(value.replace(/\./g,'[.]').split(' ').join('|'),'gi').test($(this).text()))
    });
  });
});
```